# Yocto version control

Tags: yocto

We are struggling for version control of our application ,RFS, Uboot and kernel

We have a hello world program. Every time we are changing (patching) new functionality to the program, we have to keep a track on changes with help of version no. We need the version no of this (hello world package) should be auto incremented.
Same we have to do with Linux and uboot.

Does yocto can do this for us? Or do we have any other option to achieve this.
Please suggest us as we are new for all the capabilities of yocto.

Answer (score 10):

A full example of how you can do this:

The important part is `SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"` and `PV = "${BPV}+gitr${SRCPV}"`

```
DESCRIPTION = "Hello World"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://README.md;md5=8386d486d9e820c480636608de5c2d98"

SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
BPV = "0.1.0"
PV = "${BPV}+gitr${SRCPV}" 

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

SRC_URI = " git://example/hello_world.git;protocol=http \
"

inherit autotools

RDEPENDS_${PN} += " \
    hello-world-runtime-dependency \
"
```

Answer (score 3):

As already[pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33661855/695442) you have to use `SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"`. To have a version number that changes on each update the [PV](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PV) variable needs to be tweaked in your recipe.

```
LINUX_VERSION ?= "3.14"
PV = "${LINUX_VERSION}+git${SRCPV}"
```

You can check the [OpenEmbedded kernel recipe](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/jethro/meta/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto_3.14.bb#L29) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in feature for this in yocto to my knowledge. However, you can write your own check mechanism and place it in do_fetch_prepend. Then set the SRCREV programmatically with d.setVar('SRCREV', myshasum).

Answer (score 0):

An option for auto-updates is to set SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}" then have a script that sets PV and/or PR in the recipe. When the recipe is changed, it forces a fetch and AUTOREV means it pulls from HEAD.

Comment: You do not need that script. everything is included already in our kernel recipe we do the following:
```
LINUX_VERSION ?= "3.14"
PR = "r0"
PV = "${LINUX_VERSION}+git${SRCPV}"
```